# Removing Carriage Return (Control-M) in Groovy

Tags: javascript, groovy

My file is having unwanted Control-M characters at the end of the records and because of this file is not getting processed.

**Sample file (CSV)**
[image: Sample file]

Please suggest how can I use ReplaceAll function in Groovy to remove it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work....

```
csvFileContent.replaceAll("\r\n", "\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

This depends on your shell/OS; try "^M" (in the ReplaceAll function), but this is entered by first **pressing the "v" key while holding the "control" key down, then pressing the "return"** key.